# Wcf web get method execute twice

Tags: .net, json, wcf, rest

I have the above

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Get_Flights/{partnerCode}/{from_airport_code}/{to_airport_code}/{date_from}/{date_to}/{round_trip}/{direct_flight}/{adults}/{kidA}/{kids}/{infants}/{airline_code}/{service_class}/{includeWebFares}/{includeServiceFee}/{LangId}",
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> Get_Flights(string partnerCode,
         string from_airport_code,
         string to_airport_code,
         string date_from,
         string date_to, string round_trip, string direct_flight,
         string adults, string kidA, string kids, string infants,
        string airline_code, string service_class, string includeWebFares, string includeServiceFee, string LangId);
```

and the above

```
   public List<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> Get_Flights(string partnerCode,
         string from_airport_code,
         string to_airport_code,
         string date_from,
         string date_to, string round_trip, string direct_flight,
         string adults, string kidA, string kids, string infants, string airline_code, 
        string service_class,string includeWebFares, string includeServiceFee,string LangId)
    { //get data from webservice}
```

For a reason that i cannot understand for one call the public method run twice. I have also another 53 webmethods(get,post) in the service and all run ok. 
I will appriciate any help.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling that service!

Comment: There is without meaning, the code has many classes and many lines of code. But finally produces a dataset that i convert it. This happens ok.

Comment: Besides i have many methods which play with the same logic.

Comment: I asked so as its seems to be problem in conuming code more than the service code which you have posted in your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my question. The problem was that the webmethod was working ok BUT when the data become bigger the problem starts. So solution for my problem is put to the webconfig the above on the behavior:

```
<dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="123456" />
```

also at servrice class

```
ServeiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode= InstanceContextMode.perSession)
```

and at iservice

```
ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)
```

After that everything works fine.